# How do computer power supply testers simulate loads without using large resistors?

Tags: power-supply, resistors, testing

I notice that commercial computer power supply testers are pretty small devices. However, I would expect such devices to have a 50W resistor at a minimum which is a pretty large item. Do they squeeze a big wattage resistor into their device somehow, or do they have a way of simulating a 50 Watt load without using a 50 Watt resistor?

Comment: [Releveant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5dNxzzuMTB8)

Comment: At 50 watts they almost certainly use resistive dissipation - remember, until recently people used glass encapsulated 60 watt resistors merely for that fact that they incidentally put out a little bit of light when they got hot.  At higher power levels, it would be theoretically possible to use an inverter to backfeed waste energy to the mains supply, but the safety issues so resulting (re-energizing dead mains circuits, etc) bring a lot of regulatory issues into play and would typically only be justified in a high power industrial setting, ie, dynamometers.

Comment: With a fast fan it can be made quite small and dissipate 50 W.

Comment: The CPU cooling fan of a computer dissipates around 100W of power easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing further research I found that that retail "computer power supply testers" are just voltage meters. They do not test the power supply using the actual loads found in typical computers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simulation, they simply use active devices with a heatsink to set a load value. Most commercial active load can be constant current or R equivalent and profiles.
You might read [this](http://www.edn.com/design/analog/4368416/Design-a-100A-active-load-to-test-power-supplies) (rather old but still very valid) to gain some understanding.

Comment: Indeed, if it converts electrical energy to heat it is *functionally* a resistor, regardless if the label identifies it as a power resistor, a power transistor... or a hair dryer.

Comment: To some extent what Chris says is true. However, perusing the article linked, its circuit exhibits 100A *transient* currents, which your hair drier might not exhibit except on startup (because it has a motor).